# Why CPU Softirq time is high sometimes on our PostgreSQL server? How can I find the cause?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, irq

Sometimes softIRQ time increases as you see in the server log. Is it normal? how can I find the cause?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Postgre SQL 12

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What does your application's response time look like during those times, or database query execution times? Meeting your service performance objectives - is it fast - is far more important than host level resource metrics.

Comment: @JohnMahowald 
In fact database becomes so slow or sometimes halted! one time I could not ping the server!